# Accessing Postgres in a GKE cluster from a Dataproc cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-dataproc, gke-networking

I have two cluster in GCP.

1. GKE cluster which has only postgres installed using Kubernetes.
2. A dataproc cluster.

Now if i make the service of postgres as Internally load balanced to provide security i can access it using my VPN configurations .

But the problem got while accessing the Postgres from the dataproc cluster. The communication wasnt successful. Hence i had to made the postgres public load balanced.

I want suggestions here how we can achieve security here.? making database less accessible however it should be still accessible by Dataproc cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the **LoadBancer** to expose the service directly and not using the Ingress you can use the **IP whitelisting** option to Whitelist your **Data Cluster** IPs.

Example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
ports:
    - port: 8765
      targetPort: 9376
  selector:
    app: example
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 79.78.77.76
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 130.211.204.1/32
  - 130.211.204.2/32
```

You can add the **Data cluster** **IPs** (or the whole VPC subnet IP range in which the cluster is) in **LoadBalancer** service and only requests coming from cluster will be access the database.

Refer to the [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-cidr-ip-address-loadbalancer/) for more information

**Ingress**

If you are using the ingress to expose the database

You can use the annotation :

```
ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range
```

to whitelist the IPs

Comment: Thanks @Harsh., How do i get the dataproc cluster IP.?

Comment: you can use the Node Ips those are the one which POD uses when your request is going out kubernets cluster. If you are running 4 node 4 IPs will be there. In this case scaling node may change the IP of node. You need to set the NAT to get single for whole cluster.

Comment: As you are on GKE no need to worry just apply this NAT terraform and it will auto create the NAT gateway for you. : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-nat-gateway/tree/v1.2.3/examples/gke-nat-gateway

Comment: Thanks @harsh for the details. Much helpful

Comment: It is weird that the link provided in the answer links to a AWS EKS doc.

Comment: @NishchalDinesh Your Dataproc cluster IPs are allocated from the VPC subnet of the region, you might want to whitelist the whole subnet IP range.

Comment: @Dagang yeah at a time of pasting link i checked it's from AWS but for end user resolution of issue matter, plus i am not an employee of GCP so i forcefully have to use the GCP link. haha :) thanks for providing details on subnet part i missed it.

Comment: @NishchalDinesh Understood, thanks for your answer!